# Preserving postdata with embedded wp_query queries?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm designing a website in Wordpress. This site is one of those parallax sites where all the pages are printed on the homepage and the menu scrolls to the anchors.

That being said I am using a wp_query to pull out all the pages that are in the main menu. Furthermore I have a shortcode that I use in the content that also requires the use of wp_query.

The problem I have is that the shortcode (the embedded wp_query) is screwing up the postdata. I know when using wp_query you'd usually want to use wp_reset_postdata but in this particular situation it doesn't work because this function call will restore the postdata of the homepage and not of the currently running wp_query (sorry if I'm being unclear).

Is there a way to take a snapshot of the postdata to then restore after my shortcode? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
function my_shortcode() {
    save_postdata(); //saves the current postdata
    $query = new WP_Query();
    while( $query->have_posts() )   {
        $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    }
    my_wp_reset_postdata(); //restores the postdata to where it was before the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it working, credit goes to Nikola's question since I worked off of his idea.

```
function _save_query( $var = '_wp_query' ) {
    global $post;
    $GLOBALS[ $var ] = $post;
}

function _wp_reset_query( $var = '_wp_query' ) {
    global $post;
    $post = $GLOBALS[ $var ];
    setup_postdata( $post );
}
```

I looked at the documentation of how the loop works found [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/query.php#L0). I decided to use the same kind of setup as in Nikola's answer since it met my criteria but I used the implementation of the_post to restore the postdata. This is probably not very efficient since it's using the setup_postdata function (which I assume is overkill) but it has definitely solved my problem.

So now when I embed a wp_query I can just do the following:

```
_save_query();
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $products->have_posts() ) {
    $ob .= '<ul class="group-posts">';
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        $products->the_post();
        $ob .= '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
    }
    _wp_reset_query();
    $ob .= '</ul>';
}
```

Side question/note: What's the etiquette for marking an answer as the correct answer? I'd feel bad accepting my answer as the correct one when Nikola helped me reach it?

Comment: Glad that you were able to figure it out :) Well you just accept your answer, since that's the proper answer for your question, thanks for giving me the credits - I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

By looking in the source for [`wp_reset_query()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/query.php#L104), you will see that what it does is that it simply restores the `$wp_query` global variable from another global variable(`$wp_the_query` - this is set-up together with the initial set-up for `$wp_query`, so it holds the original query).

What you can do is you can simply assign `$wp_query` to a different global variable and then later restore it. Here's an example:

```
function _save_query( $var = '_wp_query' ) {
    $GLOBALS[ $var ] = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
}

function _wp_reset_query( $var = '_wp_query' ) {
    $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS[ $var ];
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

So simply call `_save_query()` before overwriting the query(you can pass a custom variable name - this way you can store multiple `WP_Query` objects :) ).

Once you want to restore the query data, call `_wp_reset_query()` - again you can pass a string as a variable name in order to restore this exact query object.

Comment: I had tried a similar solution but it doesn't seem to work. If I call the_ID() before my shortcode it gives 8 and if I call the_ID after the shortcode I get 49. Here's what my attempt looks like: http://pastebin.com/wvsnHPtr

Comment: But you have typed `_wp_reset_query()` instead of `wp_reset_query()`. Take off the undescore. Are they your own functions? I don't get it, because it should all work fine with `wp_reset_query()`.

Answer (score 0):

`my_wp_reset_postdata`does not exist. You have to use `wp_reset_postdata()`. But in a situation where you have to chain multiple wp_queries and come back to the older ones, you can store your first query in a variable, set the new WP_query, then reset it and come back to the old one.

$wp_query stores the current loop. So you can go something like :

```
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ...

    // then later 
    $wp_query = $temp;
    // And back on tracks !
```

Comment: Note the `I'm looking for something along the lines of:` ;)

Comment: Sorry, was still typing, it got posted. I will come up with the full code for you in a minute

Comment: It's not really that I'm losing the variable to a new query, it's that once I call $wp_query_2->the_post() it'll overwrite the global data and I don't know how to reset it to $wp_query->the_post(). Nikola's answer seems to be in the right direction but it doesn't seem to do the trick.